# How would I push to GitHub with a tag

Tags: git, github-actions

So I have an action that triggered when tag is pushed, but I can’t seem to push with a tag so it triggers the action.

How would I do this?

Comment: Read in the detailed answer how to push tags to repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like what you're trying to do is push a tag that would trigger some sort of action.
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging
Take a look at the link above, that goes over how to annotate and share tags.